# Using Greensock JS with WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gsap

Checked around various tutorial/forum sites but can't crack this problem I'm having getting Greensock JS Animation Platform running in WordPress.

I've got a WP site up and running and have linked all relevant (as far as I can see) GS files as follows:

```
function greensock_scripts()
{

wp_register_script( 'mytweenmax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/minified  /TweenMax.min.js');
wp_register_script( 'myeasepack', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/minified/easing/EasePack.min.js');
wp_register_script( 'mycssplugin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/minified/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js');
wp_register_script( 'mygsext', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/greensock_ext.js');
wp_register_style( 'mygscss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/gs_styles.css');

wp_enqueue_script( 'mytweenmax' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'myeasepack' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'mycssplugin' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'mygsext' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'mygscss' );  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'greensock_scripts' );
```

Double-checked pathway to files ... all OK.

The greensock_ext.js contains my call to scripts:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var thebox = document.getElementById("mybox");
    TweenMax.to(thebox, 2, {left:"632px", delay:4});
}
```

Styles are working:

```
#mycontainer{
width:600px;
height:50px;
background-color: #ccc;
}

#mybox{
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:#f00;
position:relative;


}
```

All good, but can't get any animation happening :(

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Mekong

Comment: Don't worry about, guys. I got it sorted.

Comment: Could you please post your solution above so it can help others.. thanks :)